# JS RegExp to match none or all

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a RegExp that will match a string if there are zero or more "options". For example, I have these three strings that I wish to match:

```
'user'
'user/1'
'user/1/admin'
```

I currently have this:

```
/^user(?:(?:\/){1}([%a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\s,]+))*$/g
```

This will match them all but it will only return the last matched option. So on the 2nd string, it will remember `'1'`. On the 3rd, it will remember `'admin'`. On the 3rd, I'd like it to remember `['1', 'admin']`.

This would need to be dynamic to allow 1 or unlimited options.

This is so I can define something like `user:args` and I can then return the args.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just split on `/` and then just look at the last element of the array for the "remembered" value? (e.g. `'user/1/admin'.split('/')` returns `['user','1','admin']`)

Comment: This is part of a larger system that is using regex. I wouldn't be able to handle this with a simple split and then a shift to remove the user part.

Comment: It's still more versatile than hard-coding complex regexes into the code.

Comment: @MitchellSimoens: Are you using node.js with express.js? Regardless, please include the actual framework, so that you won't get answers which you can't use.

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm not using a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Regex can only remember the last iteration. However, you can do it writing some complex code.. or match using

```
^user((\/[\w %,-]+)+)?$
```

and then split the match `$1` by `/`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `string.split()` that should meet your requirements.

```js
var strings = [
  'user',
  'user/1',
  'user/1/admin',
  'blah/ignore/this/user',
  'blah/ignore/this/too/user/1/admin',
  'blah/this/should/also/be/ignored/user/1'
];

function getArgs(str,base) {
  // If the string doesn't contain the requested base, ignore.
  if (str.indexOf(base) === -1) return undefined;
  var options = str.split(base)[1];
  return options.substring(1).split('/');
}

strings.forEach(function(str) {
  console.log(str,getArgs(str,'user'));
});
```